# Create and calculate new rows based on other rows condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the dataframe as follow:

**dataframe generator:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year':[2000,2001,2002]*3,
    'id':['a']*3+['b']*3+['c']*3,
    'othernulcol': ['xyz']*3+[np.nan]*4+['tyu']*2,
    'val':[np.nan,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
})
```

**data looks like:**

```
   year id othernulcol  val
0  2000  a         xyz  NaN
1  2001  a         xyz  2.0
2  2002  a         xyz  3.0
3  2000  b         NaN  4.0
4  2001  b         NaN  5.0
5  2002  b         NaN  6.0
6  2000  c         NaN  7.0
7  2001  c         tyu  8.0
8  2002  c         tyu  9.0
```

I want to create new 3 rows from 2000 to 2002 that is the `sum` of row with id = `a` and `b` in the same year. `othernulcol` is just other column in dataframe. When creating new rows, just set those cols as np.NaN

**Expected output:**

```
    year  id othernulcol   val
0   2000   a         xyz   NaN
1   2001   a         xyz   2.0
2   2002   a         xyz   3.0
3   2000   b         NaN   4.0
4   2001   b         NaN   5.0
5   2002   b         NaN   6.0
6   2000   c         NaN   7.0
7   2001   c         tyu   8.0
8   2002   c         tyu   9.0
9   2000  ab         NaN   NaN
10  2001  ab         NaN  10.0
11  2002  ab         NaN  12.0
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: Why is ouput `10, 12` ? What means `othernulcol is just other column in dataframe. When creating new rows, just set those cols as np.NaN` ? It means all non numeric columns are set to `NaN` ? Or columns from list? Or something else?

Comment: Just set it as None or anything. The `othernulcol` means they are not need

Comment: So need specify columns for sum? Here `id, val` columns only?

Comment: Your solution works very well, I am checking if everything works with my actual data.

Comment: Super, I add filtering by `cols` for avoid join strings columns, if all columns are numeric (without `id`) is possible omit `cols`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter values by categories and convert `year` to index for align same years from another DataFrame, sum values by [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) and append to original DataFrame by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
cols = ['id','val']

df1 = df[df['id'].eq('a')].set_index('year')[cols]
df2 = df[df['id'].eq('b')].set_index('year')[cols]

df = pd.concat([df, df1.add(df2).reset_index()], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    year  id othernulcol  val
0   2000   a         xyz  NaN
1   2001   a         xyz  2.0
2   2002   a         xyz  3.0
3   2000   b         NaN  4.0
4   2001   b         NaN  5.0
5   2002   b         NaN  6.0
6   2000   c         NaN  7.0
7   2001   c         tyu  8.0
8   2002   c         tyu  9.0
9   2000  ab         NaN  NaN
10  2001  ab         NaN  7.0
11  2002  ab         NaN  9.0
```

Comment: Hi, your solution works good. However my actual data is a bit more complicated. It actually requires multi-level index. In this case, how to solve this? I can by=pass with loop, but it is good to know if there is anyway to work with multi-level index here

Comment: @PTQuoc -  Be free change data sample with MultiIndex, hard to know without data

Comment: so sorry, my bad, everything works excellently! I just forgot the `inplace`. Once again, thank you so much

Comment: One more question, just curious, if the `val` column is the average, then how do we do in this case?

Comment: @PTQuoc - in real data are multiple columns for processing? Like `id, val, col1, col2, coln` ? And need all sum only `val` for mean?

Comment: yes, the same like your solution, but `val` now is the mean of `a` and `b` of the same year.

Comment: @PTQuoc - Then use `df = pd.concat([df, df1.add(df2).reset_index().assign(val = lambda x: x.val / 2)], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @PTQuoc - for mean divide `2`

Comment: I think I should go to sleep. That is way too easy that I cant figure it out. So sorry and thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be as follows:

- Select rows from `df` with `df.id.isin(['a','b']` (see [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)) and apply [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to `year`.
- For the aggregration, use `sum` for column `id`. For column `val` use a lambda function to apply [`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html), which allows `skipna=False`.
- Finally, use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to add the result to the original `df` with ignoring the index.

```
out = pd.concat([df,df[df.id.isin(['a','b'])]\
                 .groupby('year', as_index=False)\
                     .agg({'id':'sum', 
                           'val':lambda x: x.sum(skipna=False)})], 
                ignore_index=True)
    
print(out)

    year  id othernulcol  val
0   2000   a         xyz  NaN
1   2001   a         xyz  2.0
2   2002   a         xyz  3.0
3   2000   b         NaN  4.0
4   2001   b         NaN  5.0
5   2002   b         NaN  6.0
6   2000   c         NaN  7.0
7   2001   c         tyu  8.0
8   2002   c         tyu  9.0
9   2000  ab         NaN  NaN
10  2001  ab         NaN  7.0
11  2002  ab         NaN  9.0
```

Comment: hmmm, but if change order `a,b` rows - e.g. swap it get `ba` instead `ab` in ouput `id`, another problem is `groupby` is slow, so better avoid it. `ignore_index=True` in `concat` is better like `.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @jezrael: thanks for the comments. Yes, `ignore_index=True` of course. Evidently, `a, b` rows ought to be in order, but in this case they are (and one could sort them otherwise). Finally, yes `groupby` will be noticeably slower on a large dataset, but it is flexible if the OP wants to add aggregations.

Comment: yes, if need `median` or some another aggregation function like `sum, mean` it is only solution